# get user's name regardless of authentication-realm

Tags: java, authentication, jax-ws

I'm developing a webservice in Java on a stack of Metro and Tomcat, and my problem is with the user authentication. I understand Tomcat can make use of several external authentication realms, such as JDBCRealm or JNDIRealm, and I want my endusers to configure their Tomcat installation for their respective realm.

Now, what I need in my webservice-methods is the user name (or id, something unique) the user has used to log in, regardless of the concrete realm. Where do I get it? Obviously I've searched for the wrong key words so far - is there a specific name for the concept I want to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logged-in user is available by [`WebServiceContext#getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) which returns a [`Principal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) instance which in turn has a [`getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html#getName%28%29) method.

E.g.

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

@WebMethod
public String hello() {
    Principal user = context.getUserPrincipal();
    return (user != null) ? user.getName() : "(not logged in)";
}
```

This is under the covers obtained from [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) by the way.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks exactly as what I need.